# In spite of onCollision handling my character falls through the platform

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

This is the mechanism I use to prevent this bad accident happening to my beloved character:

```
void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    print(
        "other is $other and intersectionPoints length is ${intersectionPoints.length}");
    if (other is Brick && intersectionPoints.length == 2) {
      isOnGround = true;
      final intersectionsVector=
          (intersectionPoints.elementAt(0) + intersectionPoints.elementAt(1)) /
              2;
      final collisionVector = absoluteCenter - intersectionsVector;
      final penetrationDistance = size.x / 2 - collisionVector.length;
      collisionVector.normalize();
      if (Vector2(0, -1).dot(collisionVector) > 0.9) {
        isOnGround = true;
      }

      position += collisionVector.scaled(penetrationDistance);
    }

    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  }
```

Most of my game and even variables are inspired from the Flame's Ember character,
The only difference is Ember game doesn't use cameraComponent.follow(player) but I do.
Everthing works fine and my character is walking happily and all of a sudden he gets passed through the ground and dies.

So I added this to see what is what:

```
  print(
        "other is $other and intersectionPoints length is ${intersectionPoints.length}");
```

The only problem I see is intersectionPoints length are some times 1 and maybe that's the time my character falls. and I don't know why.
I'm using CircleHitBox for my player and RectanglehitBox for my Bricks(platform).
So how can I handle this better. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you have noticed, `intersectionPoints` doesn't necessarily contain 2 entries, you should even get an error when that happens since you are doing `elementAt(1)` and there might not be and element on that index.

If you want to take the average of the intersection points I recommend to do something like this:

```dart
final Vector2 average = Vector2.zero;
for (final point in intersectionPoints) {
  average.add(point);
}
average.scale(1/intersectionPoints.length);
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't get any errors because length is checked so elementAt(1) always exists

Comment: Wow, I'm talking to the creator. Thank you very much for this great tool.

Comment: Ah, missed that you checked the length, that makes sense then.
Glad you enjoy Flame! :)